# Finding the inverse of a matrix by elementary transformations.

Tags: matrices, inverse

While using the *elementary transformation* method to find the inverse of a matrix, our goal is to convert the given matrix into an identity matrix.

We can use  three transformations:-
1) Multiplying a row by a constant
2) Adding a multiple of another row
3) Swapping two rows

The thing is, I can't seem to figure out what to *do* to achieve that identity matrix. There are **so** many steps which I can start off with, but how do I know *which one* to do? I think of one step to get a certain position to a $1$ or a $0$, and then get a new matrix. Now again there are so many options, it's boggling.

Is there some specific procedure to be followed? Like, first convert the top row into:
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}
Then do the second row and then the third?

What do I start off with? I hope I've made my question clear enough.

---

Thanks to @Brian M. Scott.

$P.S:$ Does anyone have any other methods? Brian's works perfectly, but it's always great to know more than one method. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get a non-zero entry in the upper lefthand corner by swapping to rows if necessary. If that entry is $a_{11}\ne 0$, multiply the first row by $a_{11}^{-1}$ to get a $1$ in the upper lefthand corner. Now use operation (2) to get $0$’s in the rest of the first column.

Now get a non-zero entry in the $a_{22}$ position, the second entry in the second row, by swapping the second row with one of the lower rows if necessary, and multiply the (possibly new) second row by $a_{22}^{-1}$ to get a $1$ in the $a_{22}$ position. Then use operation (2) to get $0$’s in the rest of the second column; notice that since $a_{21}$, the first element in the second row, is $0$, this will not affect anything in the first column.

At this point your matrix looks like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&a_{13}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
0&1&a_{23}&\dots&a_{2n}\\
0&0&a_{33}&\dots&a_{3n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&a_{n3}&\dots&a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Continue in the same fashion: get a non-zero entry in the $a_{33}$ position by swapping row $3$ with a lower row if necessary, multiply row $3$ by a suitable constant to make $a_{33}=1$, and use operation (2) to $0$ out the rest of the third column.

If at any point the necessary operation is impossible, your original matrix was not invertible.

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally a procedure; I know what *exactly* I have to do.

Comment: @mikhailcazi: You’re very welcome.

Comment: It might be important to know why this method works. It's a rather simple and basic reason connected with what "elementary operations by rows" actually are.

Comment: @DonAntonio I'd be interested to know why. Could you explain? :)

Comment: @mikhailcazi: You might take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481173/another-way-to-find-inverse-matrix) and its answers; I believe that one of the answers or comments also has a link to an explanation.

Comment: Every row elementary operation is a multiplication by an elementary matrix $\,E_i\;$ *from the left*, @mikhailcazi, so following the method given by Brian you get $$E_k\cdot E_{k-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot E_2 A=I$$ which means $\,E_kE_{k-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot E_1=A^{-1}\;$ ...

Comment: I'm new to this: is is the standard process of the Gauss-Jordan elimination for working out  the inverse of a square matrix by converting the matrix into the identity matrix, or did you come up with your own method for converting a square matrix into the identity matrix?

Comment: @83457: It’s the standard process.

Answer (score 1):

I give you an example of a similar approach to Brian's one.
Start from the matrix
$$A=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}1&2&0\\2&0&-1\\2&3&-1\end{array}\right]$$
First step is to write the identity matrix on right side of the matrix A.
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}1&2&0&1&0&0\\2&0&-1&0&1&0\\2&3&-1&0&0&1\end{array}\right]\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}$$
Now, you have to start to apply *elementary transformations* to the whole matrix, since on the left side the identity matrix appears.
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}1&2&0&1&0&0\\0&3&0&0&-1&1\\2&3&-1&0&0&1\end{array}\right]\begin{array}{c}a \rightarrow a\\-b+c \rightarrow b\\c\rightarrow c\end{array}$$
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}1&2&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&-1/3&1/3\\0&1&1&2&0&-1\end{array}\right]\begin{array}{c}a \rightarrow a\\b/3 \rightarrow b\\-c+2a\rightarrow c\end{array}$$
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}1&0&0&1&2/3&-2/3\\0&1&0&0&-1/3&1/3\\0&0&1&2&1/3&-4/3\end{array}\right]\begin{array}{c}a-2b \rightarrow a\\b \rightarrow b\\c-b\rightarrow c\end{array}$$

At this point, the matrix on the right side is the inverse of $A$! Namely:
$$A^{-1}=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}1&2/3&-2/3\\0&-1/3&1/3\\2&1/3&-4/3\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question. As Brian says, one way to do reduce it is making the element $a_{ii}$ 1, then making all elements of column $i$ 0. Then move onto $a_{i+1, i+1}$. I was asking for a procedure which could be followed. What procedure have you followed in your answer?

Comment: well, I managed to get all $a_{ii} = 1$ on the left hand side. I achieved this by using elementary operation reported on the rightmost side of the whole matrix. This is a method to obtain on the right hand side the inverse of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a square matrix A of order 3.
 Now by property of matrices if |A|$\neq$ 0 only then it has an inverse i.e. A should be a non singular matrix.
Assuming A to be a non singular matrix,
by property of matrices
$$(A)(A^{-1})=I$$
where I is identity matrix.
$$ $$
Now substitute the value of A and I. Use transformations as suggested above to get identity matrix in place of A and simultaneously applying those elementary transformation to the Identity matrix on RHS would give you the value of $A^{-1}$ .

So basically the equation changes to $$(I)(A^{-1})=A^{-1}$$

Comment: In case you need me to add the steps of transformation do comment.